# What type of frame could this be?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, identify-this-bike, vintage

Recently purchased this 1x11 rebuild. Decals have been removed and it has a fresh powder coat. The stripes are coloured electrical tape so don't go by that... I've heard it could be a Miyata or Nishiki but can't find either that have an exact replica. The lugs seem to be very unique.

Any ideas of the make/model/year?

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: It is at least somewhat distinctive.  A closeup of the rear dropout area might be helpful.  But I'm guessing it's later than 1990.

Comment: Well it started as a multiple chainwheel bike - the extra cable holders suggest that.  The yellow is a repaint for sure.  The black tape holding the cable on... that's really detracting, would look better with some proper shiny chrome cable clips.  Not sure what the big pog of yellow tape is on the seat tube - is it just holding the reflector on?  That's a poor place for it cos the seat stays will obscure.  I see marks on the bottom of the right side seat stay - are they original decals showing through?  Try and read them under a strong light.

Comment: Oh - its a gorgeous bike too.  You should ride it!  I'd consider a contrasting bartape though - yellow gets dirty about as fast as white bartape does.   Maybe deep red leather-like bartape, to match the front hub?

Comment: Don't want to be rude, but... @Criggie, why does this bike deserve identification and others (mostly bmx) not?

Comment: The cabling is bizarre.  There are welded-on cable guides that are not used.

Comment: @k102 - Most BMX bikes are generic Chinese things that cannot be differentiated.

Comment: I suspect that the bike was not originally a 10-speed.

Comment: @Criggie yeah the yellow tape was just there to mount the reflector temporarily until i get an LED.

Comment: And @Daniel R Hicks there was only cable routing for the rear and front derailler and since its a 1x im only using the one side. Aswell the back brake had to be rimmy jigged to make it work, hence the tape and stick on cable mounts.. Also temporary

Comment: That's what I mean.  There's no provision for the rear brake cable.  And the rear derailer cable is missing guides for the top part.  It may be that the bike originally had downtube shifters (though that doesn't explain the brakes).  But inspect carefully in the area of that cable guide near the top of the down tube to see if there are signs of a downtube shifter having been attached there.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks your making me want to strip the paint to see whats been done to it. I cant see any evidence of them being removed. Also dont understand why one was left if they did remove them. Im thinking it is stock.. It must of had the old school shifters on the down tube and maybe there is an internal way to route the rear brake. Thoughts?

Comment: It must have had a clip on it for the rear brake.. It helps a bit to narrow down what it is and age but still nothing solid

Comment: @k102 several reasons - BMXs tend to be very similar, with no significant distinguishing features.  Many  "ID my BMX" questions are a bare frame and maybe a fork, will never be reassembled and ridden.  This yellow and red bike has features that are distinctive, and can help date it.  There's a level of bike archaeology trying to see if it has/had downtube shifters or other dateable features.   Finally, OP is actively riding this bike..  That alone makes it more interesting to me so I choose to put more effort into helping.  We're diverging from topic, so try [chat] for less structured things.

Comment: Rear brake pads look like they’re upside down. If they’re cartridge pads make sure they face the right way so the pads don’t come out

Comment: @Swifty yeah there upside down but have a tiny screw holding them in place. I liked how it looked flaring upwards, also they fitted more flush on the rim that way for some reason

Comment: What are the extra holes by the hubs? Are they for disk brakes?

Comment: @WilliamPatton - The holes in the dropouts are for fenders.

Comment: The brake pads are designed to go the correct way around; the tiny screw isn’t there to stop the pads being pulled out when the cartridge is the wrong way around. It’s effectively doing all of the braking. If the pads aren’t flush with the rim then consider replacing the pads.